# Value of textBox of form1 have to appear in textBox of form2

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++, textbox, c++-cli

I need to show the value of textBox1 of Form1 (parent) in textBox2 of Form2 (child) after pressing an option in a menu (ie. to open the child form). Basically a parent-child communication problem. I've tried to modify [this](http://blog.iandreev.com/?p=194) to do what I need but no luck, I get:

```
Used_values.h(30) : warning C4101: 'HERE' : unreferenced local variable
Used_values.h(560) : error C2065: 'HERE' : undeclared identifier
```

Here you can find the relevant parts of my code:

Form1 (parent):

```
#pragma once
#include "Used_values.h"

namespace Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected:
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1_generalMenu;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  usedValues_ToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1_waterDepth;
    //(more code...)

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            //(more code...)
            this->textBox1_waterDepth = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            //(more code...)
            // 
            // textBox1_waterDepth
            // 
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Segoe UI", 10));
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->Location = System::Drawing::Point(336, 185);
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->Name = L"textBox1_waterDepth";
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 25);
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->TabIndex = 1;
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->Text = L"2170";
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Right;
            this->textBox1_waterDepth->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_waterDepth_TextChanged);
            //(more code...)
        }

#pragma endregion
    //(more code...)
    private: System::Void usedValues_ToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Used_values^ used_values = gcnew Used_values();
                 used_values->StartPosition = FormStartPosition::CenterParent;
                 used_values->ShowDialog();
                 used_values->HERE = textBox1_waterDepth->Text;
             }
    //(more code...)
};
}
```

Used_values (child):

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

namespace Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm {

    public ref class Used_values : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Used_values(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String ^HERE;
        }

    protected:
        ~Used_values()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues;
    //(more code...)

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            //(more code...)
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
(more code...)
            // 
            // textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues
            // 
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Location = System::Drawing::Point(435, 10);
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Name = L"textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues";
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 25);
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TabIndex = 1;
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Right;
            this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Used_values::textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues_TextChanged);
            //(more code...)
        }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Text = HERE;
         }
};
}
```

So, what it should appear in textBox of Form2 (Used_values) is 2170 (default value of textBox in Form1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution! thanks to bash.d for all the support =)

1. change in the constructor of child form to receive a String parameter:

   ```
   public:
       Form2(String^ text)
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           this->textBox2->Text = text;
       }
   ```
2. show child form when a button is clicked in parent form:

   ```
   private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Form2^ form = gcnew Form2(this->textBox1->Text);
        form->Show();
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference in the constructor of `Used_values`

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

namespace Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm {

public ref class Used_values : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Used_values(System::String^ here)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HERE = here;
    }

protected:
    ~Used_values()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues;
         System::String^ HERE;
//(more code...)

private:
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        //(more code...)
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        (more code...)
        // 
        // textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues
        // 
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Location = System::Drawing::Point(435, 10);
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Name = L"textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues";
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 25);
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TabIndex = 1;
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TextAlign = 
        System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Right;
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TextChanged += 
        gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Used_values::textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues_TextChanged);
        //(more code...)
    }
#pragma endregion

 private: System::Void textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Text = HERE;
     }
};
}


Used_values(System::String^ here)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String ^HERE = here;
    }
```

And don't use `void` as argument, this is `C`-style!

**EDIT**

```
#pragma once
#include "Used_values.h"

namespace Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

protected:
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1_generalMenu;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  usedValues_ToolStripMenuItem;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1_waterDepth;
//(more code...)

private:
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        //(more code...)
        this->textBox1_waterDepth = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        //(more code...)
        // 
        // textBox1_waterDepth
        // 
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Segoe UI", 10));
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->Location = System::Drawing::Point(336, 185);
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->Name = L"textBox1_waterDepth";
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 25);
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->TabIndex = 1;
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->Text = L"2170";
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Right;
        this->textBox1_waterDepth->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_waterDepth_TextChanged);
        //(more code...)
    }

#pragma endregion
//(more code...)
private: System::Void usedValues_ToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Used_values^ used_values = gcnew Used_values();
             used_values->StartPosition = FormStartPosition::CenterParent;
             used_values->ShowDialog();
             used_values->HERE = textBox1_waterDepth->Text;
         }
//(more code...)
};
}
```

Used_values (child):

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

namespace Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm {

public ref class Used_values : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Used_values()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

String ^HERE; //declared HERE as public


protected:
    ~Used_values()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues;
//(more code...)

private:
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        //(more code...)
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
  (more code...)
        // 
        // textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues
        // 
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Location = System::Drawing::Point(435, 10);
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Name = L"textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues";
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 25);
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TabIndex = 1;
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Right;
        this->textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Used_values::textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues_TextChanged);
        //(more code...)
    }
 #pragma endregion

private: System::Void textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Text = HERE;
     }
};
}
```

Changed contents according to [this](http://blog.iandreev.com/?p=194).

Comment: thanks for that, but I need to use what is in variable HERE in Form1 instead of initializing HERE with "here" in Form2. BTW, both Forms are already created.

Comment: When you are passing a `reference`, you are passing the original object and all changes will be visible in form2, too.

Comment: I added your suggestion and it gives an error: `\Used_values.h(560) : error C2065: 'HERE' : undeclared identifier`, it points to this line: `textBox1_waterDepthUsedValues->Text = HERE;`

Comment: Have you added `HERE` to your `private` members? Like `private: System::String^ HERE;`?

Comment: I got the same errors, could you please post an example based on my code?

Comment: I used your code and made some changes to it. See the `constructor` and your `private` members.

Comment: thanks for that, I added it but new errors appeared:

(1)`Form1.h(608) : error C2512: 'Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm::Used_values::Used_values' : no appropriate default constructor available`

(2)`Form1.h(611) : error C2248: 'Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm::Used_values::HERE' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm::Used_values'`

(3)`Used_values.h(52) : see declaration of 'Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm::Used_values::HERE'`

(4)`Used_values.h(21) : see declaration of 'Vp_vs_gasconcentration_WindowsForm::Used_values'`

Comment: they refer to:
(1-parent form)`Used_values^ used_values = gcnew Used_values();`
(2-parent form)`used_values->HERE = textBox1_waterDepth->Text;`
(3-child form)`System::String^ HERE;`
(4-child form)`public ref class Used_values : public System::Windows::Forms::Form`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26996/discussion-between-bash-d-and-gery)

Comment: You are welcome. Took you a while, but I bet the relieve feels great ;)